# My mldonkey doesn't work due to "Too many open files"

Tags: linux, file-sharing

On my NAS (an incredibly basic and reliable [DNS-323](http://www.dlink.ca/DNS-323)), I use mldonkey to download files.
It worked quite well during the last 3 years, but it seems now mldonkey doesn't work.

Indeed, each time I start mldonkey, it crashes after a few hours of execution, complaining for `Too many open files`. Due to the fact mldonkey worked without any trouble during years, I wonder what can make it fail.

According to some web results, I tried to `ulimit -n 5000`, but it didn't changed anything : mldonkey continued to fail.

What's more, it seems that when I restart mldonkey (but not the NAS), it fails far faster (which lead me to think open files are not mldonkey ones.

So.
How can I check which files are open, and what could I do to fix that?

Comment: as per Thibaud's answer : run lsof and post the output to mldonkey forum or bugtracker, cause mldonkey shouldn't exceed the configured limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **lsof** to see wich files are open (apt-get install lsof on Debian-based linux)

List files open by user *root*:

```
lsof -u root
```

List files open by proc xxx:

```
lsof -p xxx
```

Show the number of files open by proc xxx:

```
lsof -p xxx | wc -l
```

When you change ulimit i am not sure that live process take the new value. 
Check also your `/etc/security/limits.conf`. It may define higher limit than 5000 by default. Notice that **ulimit** *Limit user resources* and if your NAS launch each process under the same user, 5000 doesn't seem so high.